# Vertical centering in nested RelativeLayout inside a ListView

Tags: android, listview, center, android-relativelayout, vertical-alignment

I tried to nest two RelativeLayouts as rows of a ListView and center the contents of the nested layout vertically. No matter what I tried, I couldn't get it to work:

[image: screenshot:]

This is my XML layout, I know it's a bit of a mess (also tried LinearLayouts to no success):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/check"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/date_time_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:bufferType="spannable">
    </TextView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/date_time_container"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_time"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:bufferType="spannable"
            android:text="">
        </TextView>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/date_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/urgent" 
            android:contentDescription="@string/icon"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I already made sure to inflate the rows correctly in the adapter, as suggested in other threads:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.task_row, parent, false);         
}
```

Any ideas? I'm sure it must be something minor. Thanks!

**Edit:** 
In Eclipse the layout is showing correctly, it appears that nesting the layout inside a ListView row somehow messes up the layout:
[image]

**Edit 2:**
I thought I'd got somewhere by using an EditText. But unless there's a way to make it look the same as a TextView I'm back to the drawing board :(

**Edit 3:**
I finally solved it by using a LinearLayout and android:gravity="center_vertical" in the TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/check"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/date_time_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:bufferType="spannable">
    </TextView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/date_time_container"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        android:background="@color/grey"
        >
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/date_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:bufferType="spannable"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:text="20:00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
             />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/urgent" 
            android:contentDescription="@string/icon"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `layout_height` of the views inside the root `RelativeLayout` to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same result, the TextView is in the upper left corner and not centered.

Comment: Strange, I tried it and it works. Note that there is a circular dependency and that you have to remove the line `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/icon"`.

Comment: I changed the layout as you suggested but it didn't change anything. The problem appears to be that inside a ListView, the LayoutParams are not working correctly. I implemented a subclass of SimpleCursorAdapter and the Layout is inflated in newView(). The graphical layout tab in eclipse is showing the layout correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I found a workaround, see original post.